# How to bind <C-U> to <Cmd><BS> in vimrc?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, cut-copy-paste

I understand that `<C-W>` is `backward-kill-word` and I have bound this to <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>BS</kbd> and it works.

But now I want to bind `<C-U>` to <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>BS</kbd>. Is this possible? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: Does this sequence produce a key code that can be detected by Vim? If you go into Insert mode in Vim and type `Ctrl+V` followed by `Cmd-Backspace`, does it actually insert anything? You might need to configure your O.S. and your terminal to get them to send a key code for this key all the way to Vim.

Comment: BTW, Ctrl+W and Ctrl+U are more or less universal on Unix. They will work in all shells and generally everything that takes any input from the keyboard. Rather than trying to override them everywhere, you should consider adopting them and getting used to them.

Comment: Wait, do you want Ctrl-U to send Command-BS, or vice-versa? You wrote the former, but I suspect the latter

Comment: @filbranden: I doesn't generate anything, I also checked how to define it in Terminal Preference > Profiles > Keyboard, but there it has `option`, `control`, `shift` but no `command`...

Comment: @D.BenKnoble: The latter, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I'm not surprised... That's the usual on Mac, the Command key is usually reserved for Mac-specific shortcuts and application-specific shortcuts and Unix-like terminals usually only use Control and Alt/Meta/Option, so it's not that surprising that it's not offering you to map a combination that includes Command...

Comment: It's a little bit sad that I have to change from `shift BS` `cmd BS` to `<C-W>` `<C-U>` respectively. While it's reasonable that the `cmd` key should not be sent to applications but reserved for OS.